# "Code" on Linux. How to and prereqs to compile .NET 4.5..4.6 core/portable library or executable from Linux?

Tags: linux, cross-platform, .net-4.5, cross-compiling

I just got [Visual Studio Code for Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com//downloadory) installed on xubuntu 14.04.2-desktop-amd64. I have it extracted in my home folder. In the /home/Visual Studio Code subdirectory into its own subdi I have a subdirectory containing a .cs file to compile to an executable. Does the [Code](https://code.visualstudio.com//downloadory)  download already have the necessary files to target .NET 4.5.2 or 4.6? If not, then where should you download the .NET frameworks 4.5, 4.6? Microsoft, the Ubuntu Software Center, p2p torrent, ...?